# List comprehension with two conditions

Tags: python, list

It's possible to use list comprehension in python with two expression?

I.E: I have a list with dots '.' and semicolon ';' and I want to create a boolean list using the first one as a parameter:

- Dot = True
- Semicolon = False

I know how to create using only one expression:

```
L1 = [True if i == '.' for i in L2]
```

Or

```
L1 = [False if i == ';' for i in L2]
```

It's possible to merge those clausules in one list comprehension?

Edit:
[.;.;.] should transform into [True, False, True, False, True]

Comment: Can you post an input/output example?

Comment: These are syntax errors

Comment: I don't see any errors there...

Comment: The condition should be at the end of the comprehension.

Comment: @m.wasowski if you use that inline if syntax, you must always have an else clause; it's a syntax error to leave it out.

Comment: oh, right, no else clause, sorry ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[char == '.' for char in l]
```

`char == '.'` evaluates to True if the character is a period and False otherwise.

If you need a more complex transformation, you can use

```
mapping = {
    '.': True,
    ';': False,
    ...
}

[mapping[char] for char in l]
```

If you need to filter out characters other than the ones you're looking for,

```
[mapping[char] for char in l if char in mapping]
```

Comment: Although I prefer M. Wasowski's answer in this case, I think this one is more instructional. Remember that where most languages use `switch/case`, Python uses a hash map like this one to the same effect. For instance if you've got a number of possible user inputs, each of which actually MEANS something different than the input itself, `choice = hashmap[input("prompt")]` is very pythonic.

Answer (score 4):

To additionally guard against other characters, use:

```
L1 = [ch == '.' for ch in L2 if ch in '.;']
```